# Why is this IF/ELIF/ELSE not working - Python?

Tags: python

I don't know why this IF/ELIF/ELSE is not going through in python, "state_initials" exists and has a variable in it corresponding to the IF/ELIF/ELSE but it doesn't go through still.

Anything I did wrong?

I have finished my question but stack overflow will not let me post because it's mostly coded so please disregard this.

```
job_state = ""

if state_initial == "AL":
    job_state = "Alabama"
elif state_initial == "AK":
    job_state == "Alaska"
elif state_initial == "AS":
    job_state == "American Samoa"
elif state_initial == "AZ":
    job_state == "Arizona"
elif state_initial == "AR":
    job_state == "Arkansas"
elif state_initial == "CA":
    job_state == "California"
elif state_initial == "CO":
    job_state == "Colorado"
elif state_initial == "CT":
    job_state == "Connecticut"
elif state_initial == "DE":
    job_state == "Delaware"
elif state_initial == "DC":
    job_state == "District of Columbia"
elif state_initial == "FL":
    job_state == "Florida"
elif state_initial == "GA":
    job_state == "Georgia"
elif state_initial == "GU":
    job_state == "Guam"
elif state_initial == "HI":
    job_state == "Hawaii"
elif state_initial == "ID":
    job_state == "Idaho"
elif state_initial == "IL":
    job_state == "Illinois"
elif state_initial == "IN":
    job_state == "Indiana"
elif state_initial == "IA":
    job_state == "Iowa"
elif state_initial == "KS":
    job_state == "Kansas"
elif state_initial == "KY":
    job_state == "Kentucky"
elif state_initial == "LA":
    job_state == "Louisiana"
elif state_initial == "ME":
    job_state == "Maine"
elif state_initial == "MD":
    job_state == "Maryland"
elif state_initial == "MH":
    job_state == "Marshall Islands"
elif state_initial == "MA":
    job_state == "Massachusetts"
elif state_initial == "MI":
    job_state == "Michigan"
elif state_initial == "FM":
    job_state == "Micronesia"
elif state_initial == "MN":
    job_state == "Minnesota"
elif state_initial == "MS":
    job_state == "Mississippi"
elif state_initial == "MO":
    job_state == "Missouri"
elif state_initial == "MT":
    job_state == "Montana"
elif state_initial == "NE":
    job_state == "Nebraska"
elif state_initial == "NV":
    job_state == "Nevada"
elif state_initial == "NH":
    job_state == "New Hampshire"
elif state_initial == "NJ":
    job_state == "New Jersey"
elif state_initial == "NM":
    job_state == "New Mexico"
elif state_initial == "NY":
    job_state == "New York"
elif state_initial == "NC":
    job_state == "North Carolina"
elif state_initial == "ND":
    job_state == "North Dakota"
elif state_initial == "OH":
    job_state == "Ohio"
elif state_initial == "OK":
    job_state == "Oklahoma"
elif state_initial == "OR":
    job_state == "Oregon"
elif state_initial == "PW":
    job_state == "Palau"
elif state_initial == "PA":
    job_state == "Pennsylvania"
elif state_initial == "PR":
    job_state == "Puerto Rico"
elif state_initial == "RI":
    job_state == "Rhode Island"
elif state_initial == "SC":
    job_state == "South Carolina"
elif state_initial == "SD":
    job_state == "South Dakota"
elif state_initial == "TN":
    job_state == "Tennessee"
elif state_initial == "TX":
    job_state == "Texas"
elif state_initial == "UT":
    job_state == "Utah"
elif state_initial == "VT":
    job_state == "Vermont"
elif state_initial == "VA":
    job_state == "Virginia"
elif state_initial == "VI":
    job_state == "Virgin Islands"
elif state_initial == "WA":
    job_state == "Washington"
elif state_initial == "WV":
    job_state == "West Virginia"
elif state_initial == "WI":
    job_state == "Wisconsin"
elif state_initial == "WY":
    job_state == "Wyoming"
else:
    job_state = "Unknown_Location"
```

Comment: As noted in Cory Madden's answer, there is a much much better way to do this.  Also note that except for Alabama, you're doing == instead of =, which won't change state_initial

Comment: use "=" instead of "==" in job_state

Comment: If SO sets a lower limit on the question length, there *might* be a reason...

Answer (score 8):

You should really clean up your code by making a dict of your answers:

```
states = {
    'CA': 'California',
    'OR': 'Oregon',
    'WY': 'Wyoming',
    ...
}

job_state.get(state_initial, "Unknown_location")
```

Answer (score 8):

About the why part, you are not assigning. You are checking for equality in your `if`-`elif` statements.

```
elif state_initial == "ID":
    job_state == "Idaho" 
              ^^ you are using double here as well.
```

About the solution, you really should use dictionary as stated in [Cory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45738749/3134251) instead of those.